# Can I glue two 1" solid oak treads to make one 2" tread?

Tags: flooring, installation, hardwood-floor, cabinets, stairs

I am licensed floor contractor in the state of California. I am installing  solid oak treads in open steps in stairs 2"x12"x43", because open steps over 39" wide must be over 1 1/2" thick. But, 2" solid oak treads are not available at my local supplier; they are only available in 1" thick treads.

Can I glue two 1" treads to make one 2" tread and be within code?

If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just buy 10/4 rough sawn oak and plane it down to 2"?  this is a totally normal day for most staircase guys.  i am kind of surprised you are asking this question.

Comment: Done the over size, laminates not legal here for thickness on exterior, not sure about interior.

Answer (score 0):

I am a woodworker and I can tell you 2 glued up pieces would be just as strong. I don't know about code though. Keep in mind, surfaced 1X oak is actually 13/16" thick. 2 of them would be 1-5/8" thick. 1x stair treads might be actual 1" thick.

Answer (score 0):

The closest answer was #3.

The question had 2 parts:

The first part answer is: Yes, we can glue 2 solid oak treads to make one tread of minimum thickness 1½" when stair steps more than 39" width. If the steps are less than 39" wide then we can use 1" thick treads.

The second part of the question was HOW WOULD YOU DO IT? The answer is to:

- Rough the tread side going to be glued with other tread.
- Use wood glue (ARMOR WOOD GLUE) and apply it in the entire side of each tread.
- Attach the 2 treads together, using clamps and finish nails and leave it for 24 hours

Reference:

- My local hardwood distributor (Galleher  hardwood go) .
- My experience of do it  myself.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Choose the answer you like best, or invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//diy.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Home Improvement way of saying thank you.